# Validation rule on 2 picklist fields

Tags: formula, validation

I'm trying to create a validation rule formula in Salesforce, that uses two picklist fields. If the first has any value selected, the Second picklist can NOT have any value selected.
So basically if Picklist "Boiler_Type_Manual__c" is NOT Null and Picklist "Furnace_Type__c" is also NOT null, a validation rule appears: Cannot have both Boiler and Furnace Type selected!

Any help would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: Do you mean only either of the picklist should be selected and not both?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Only 1 or the other should have a value selected.

Comment: Can you create some field dependencies?

Comment: Hmmm, so if picklist A Controls picklist B then don't include any values? I didn't think of trying that. I believe the business did want some kind of explanation if a user tried to select both but not sure if it's that important.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their input and assistance. I was able to use highfive's solution successfully.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This youtube video gives a quick tutorial on exactly how to use Picklist fields in a Validation Rule.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5otBBMmDhyk

Answer (score 6):

Use `ISBLANK` on your picklist fields, after using `TEXT` to convert them to a text format.

```
AND(
    NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Boiler_Type_Manual__c))),
    NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(Furnace_Type__c)))
)
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap that in an IF statement; just use the AND.

Comment: Glad to help you. Agreed @Mike Chale, just noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

This formula might work out for you `IF( AND( TEXT(Boiler_Type_Manual__c) <> null,TEXT(Furnace_Type__c)<> null) , true, false)` .This allows only one picklist to be selected and not both.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it is still no firing. Curious: what is the true,false at the end for?

Comment: In which scenario is the validation rule not firing. True is returned if both picklist values are not null on which validation rule will be triggered, else false is returned.

Comment: It doesn't fire when I select a value in both picklists.

Comment: Is it not firing when you try to save your record?

Comment: No, it is not firing at all.

Answer (score 0):

If possible I think you should explore trying to create field dependencies..

These links may help you.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US